# Removing clock from the lock-screen

Tags: 18.04, gnome, lock-screen, desktop-background, clock

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.

I want to remove the digital clock from the lock screen because I just want to see a good wallpaper there, unobstructed.

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

***Workaround***

OS: Ubuntu 18.04

removing the clock is not possible unless digging the core files of gnome-shell files which is very difficult.

instead you can hide it by editing `ubuntu.css` file.

***Disclaimer: playing with gdm3 files is very dangerous, small mistakes will stop access to gnome desktop session. Only tty will work. i have several times reinstalled Ubuntu in such cases. although i have successfully hidden the clock-display on lock-screen. proceed with your own risk.***

open the file `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css` with below command.

```
sudo -H gedit /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css
```

search for "screen-shield" and find the below content

```
.screen-shield-clock-time {
  font-size: 72pt;
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  font-feature-settings: "tnum"; }

.screen-shield-clock-date {
  font-size: 28pt;
  font-weight: normal; }
```

then make the font-sizes to 0 like below

```
.screen-shield-clock-time {
  font-size: 0pt;
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  font-feature-settings: "tnum"; }

.screen-shield-clock-date {
  font-size: 0pt;
  font-weight: normal; }
```

save the file, Refresh Gnome-Shell Alt+F2 r Enter.

Comment: Note: for Ubuntu 19.10; the file is `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell.css`. You don't need to reboot for the changes to take effect, just `alt`-`f2`, insert `r` and press `enter`.