# How to turn off clock on login screen?

Tags: suspend, login-screen, time, clock

I like not to know time when I'm using my computer. I found how to turn it off on my desktop but I didn't find how to turn it off before login into my session (it still appears in small on top of my screen) and when I start my computer again after it has gone into standby mode (it then appears in big in the middle of the screen). 
I can live with it but now that I've got plenty of time (thx quarantine) I thought it could be the time to fix it! ;) 
Any ideas welcome and have a great day! 
Guigeek

PS: I'm not really an advanced user of commands, codes and so on, I would probably need some step by step solution.

EDIT: OS is Ubuntu 18.04.01. Question is about lock screen and login screen and not about desktop.

Comment: What's your 0S??

Comment: Basically you hv three things in which the middle thing you already achieved.. If you are using gnome desktop then the last thing is somehow possible... https://askubuntu.com/q/1107000/739431

Comment: @PRATAP Thanks, your link helped me to remove clock from the lock screen! There is still clock in small on top of my login session though but much smaller than it was for the lock screen. OS is 18.04.01 indeed.

Comment: @Guigeek I made a script to hide the clock 0n login screen.. I just waited for ur 0S..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OS: Ubuntu 18.04 Default**

***Note:***

Below is a ugly workaround..

Its not a programmatic way.

I wish some experts will do it in a programmatic way which will make me to delete this ugly workaround.

---

***Workaround***

create a script named `lghideclock.sh` (login screen hide clock) with below content in your home folder.

```
#! /bin/bash

file="/usr/local/share/gnome-shell/lghidetime.css"

install -Dv /dev/null $file

echo "@import url(/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css);

#panel .clock-display { font-size: 0px; }" > $file

update-alternatives --remove gdm3.css $file
update-alternatives --install /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gdm3.css gdm3.css $file 9999
```

then run

```
sudo /bin/bash $HOME/lghideclock.sh
```

and reboot.

You will not see the clock but the clock area is clickable and it will bring you the calendar. Even if you dont want the calendar, still we can hide it in this ugly way not a programmatic way.

***How to Undo Changes:***

Ok.. You have tried this and you hate it.. You want to go back to previous state.
Run the below commands one by one.

```
sudo update-alternatives --remove gdm3.css /usr/local/share/gnome-shell/lghidetime.css
sudo rm /usr/local/share/gnome-shell/lghidetime.css
reboot
```

***Pics***

[image]

[image]