# Suppress display of time on Ubuntu lock screen

Tags: lock-screen

I am new to Ubuntu.  I just installed it as a VM on VirtualBox.  Every time the screen locks, I see the time.  I am trying to suppress the display of the time.  According to [this page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1107000/removing-clock-from-the-lock-screen/1107032), I have to edit `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css` and set `font-size` to `0pt`.  The only file under in the folder tree `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme`, however, is `Yaru/gnome-shell-theme/gresource`, and it is binary.

There is a file `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com/ubuntu.css`, but it is 0 bytes.

**Is there any (simple) way to disable display of the time on the lock screen?**

I am using *ubuntu-20.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso*.

For now, I [disabled the lock screen](https://websiteforstudents.com/turn-off-lock-screen-on-ubuntu-20-04-18-04), but I really just want to disable display of the time.  Disabling the lock screen doesn't really help anyway because it the lock screen is momentarily displayed before being removed.  It is quite stressful being reminded of the exact time when you already know it's quite late and you're trying to get stuff done.  It certainly doesn't help one to get to sleep when one decides to call it quits.

Comment: I posted *ubuntu-20.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso* in the original question.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that I *added* the version number to the original question.

Comment: Well, none of the two links in the question posting works.

Comment: If you/re offering, thanks.  I will probably manually implement what is in the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may install and enable this extension and then click on "Remove Clock & Remove Date" Buttons on Extension Settings

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4663/customize-clock-on-lock-screen/

Customize Clock On Lock Screen Extension
[image]

[image]

Comment: I am grateful to you for having prepared the script, and I'm sorry for what I will say next, but I don't understand it enough to run it with confidence.  Maybe I can linger a bit and see if someone more knowledgeable is going to give it a spin.

Comment: Thanks, UnKNOWn!