# How do I change the lock screen font in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: fonts, lock-screen

Just installed my first Linux distro, am really impressed with the interface and functionally of it all.

I'd like to know how to change the default font for the lock screen for the time. I want to use this font for the lock screen:
https://www.dafont.com/alien-encounters.font

In particular, Alien-Encounters-Italic.ttf

[image]

So in linux I imagine I simply download the.ttf file and somehow link that .ttf file for default time font, but not sure how this is done.

Please any help would be amazing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Post is similar to your Question, follow this post [Suppress display of time on Ubuntu lock screen](https://askubuntu.com/q/1372069/739431) and do the edits as below.

edits in the below part in the css file will make the changes in the Question.

```
.unlock-dialog-clock-time {
  font-size: 64pt;
  padding-top: 42px;
  font-feature-settings: "tnum";
}

.unlock-dialog-clock-date {
  font-size: 16pt;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

changes need to be edit like below (but not limited)

```
.unlock-dialog-clock-time {
font: italic 64pt Alien Encounters;
padding-top: 42px;
font-feature-settings: "tnum"; }

.unlock-dialog-clock-date {
font: italic 16pt Alien Encounters;
font-weight: normal;
}
```

**Disclimer: Editing the css files in .gresouce files are very risky if wrong inputs are provided/edited. You may struck up with login loops or other theme issues.**

you may use this script. https://github.com/PRATAP-KUMAR/LinkOnly/blob/main/Alien%20Encounter%20Font%20for%20Lock%20Screen

Tested in Arch Linux.

[image]

Comment: YOU ARE AWESOME! THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: Sorry I know this is a little late, but where would I actually be putting that code in the github link?

Comment: Hi.. you need to download the script and run it. Thats it. https://github.com/PRATAP-KUMAR/LinkOnly/blob/main/Alien%20Encounter%20Font%20for%20Lock%20Screen

Comment: Copy paste above content of 100 lines script in a plain text file and save it as `alienFont.sh` then run the script `sudo bash ./alienFont.sh`

Comment: I copied the 100 lines into a plain script and saved it as alienFont.sh, for some reason it still isn't showing. Do I have to download the github script. And do I need to download the font from dafont.com?

Comment: For fonts.. yes you need to download it n keep in `.local/share/fonts`

Comment: after saving 100 lines in `alienFonts.sh` file. Did you run `sudo bash ./alienFonts.sh`

Comment: IT WORKS, THANKS!